# Need to write an array of objects to a file from nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have an array of objects like below that i have to write to a file with node js, the aim is to write one item per line into one file :

```
cont obj = [{a:1},{b:2}]
```

Output file content expected :

```
//file.json
{a:1}
{b:2}
```

My code without success

```
jsonfile.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(obj), 'utf-8');
/*
* [\{a:1\},\{b:2\}] <=== a string in one line with special characters 
* doesn't fit on my need
*/
```

If someone could helps me,
Thank you.

Comment: Your example output is not valid JSON. Consider using a different file extension, or writing valid JSON by using the optional arguments of `JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)` to add padding if you want a readable format, but your current approach does not make any sense.

Comment: I see, but i can name it to file.txt too, i just want to write one { ... } per line

Answer (score 3):

You could simply:

```
const text = arr.map(JSON.stringify).reduce((prev, next) => `${prev}\n${next}`);
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, text, 'utf-8');
```

(That's a slight modification of @ronapelbaum approach)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) and loop.

```
const arr = [{a:1}, {b:2}];
const filePath = "path/to/json";
for (let obj of arr)
    fs.appendFileSync (filePath, util.inspect (obj) + "\n")
```

Or, if you'd like to accumulate the data to save on write operations:

```
const arr = [{a:1}, {b:2}];
const data = arr.reduce ((a, b) => a + util.inspect (b) + "\n", "");
const filePath = "path/to/json";
fs.writeFileSync (filePath, data);
```

The final file will fit your requirements:

```
{ a: 1 }
{ b: 2 }
```

Comment: this is not such good performance..
to perform IO for each item in array...

Comment: Then accumulate and write once.

Comment: While the current question admittedly doesn't make sense, I think it's still necessary to note that `util.inspect()` does not necessarily output valid JSON (and in typical use-cases generally doesn't).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The requirement does not use JSON, therefore I used `util.inspect` .

Comment: I'm aware, but the warning is for future readers who may or may not have made that assumption otherwise.

Comment: it's me or your code? i tested on jsfiddle and it takes time to load the console, performance issue ?
const obj = [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]

const text = obj.reduce((txt, cur) => txt + '\n' + JSON.stringify(cur), '');

console.log(text)

Comment: @ikalangita What?

Answer (score -2):

when you're using the `jsonfile` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile), you don't need to use `JSON.stringify(obj)`.

in your case, you don't really want to write a valid json...

consider this:

```
const text = arr.reduce((txt, cur) => txt + '\n' + JSON.stringify(cur), '');
fs.writeFileSync(filePath, text, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to achieve?

Comment: I suggest to create the required string, then write to file